# If a vector fulfils one condition in this theorem, does it automatically fulfil both?

Tags: vector-spaces

I have this theorem:

> If $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$
>   there will exist some unique $y\in W$ such that
>
> - $(x-y)\perp u \ \ : \ \ \forall u \in W$
> - $||(x-y)|| \le ||(x-u)|| \ \ : \ \ \forall u \in W$

The second condition says that $y$ is the closest vector in $W$ to $x$. And clearly there is one and only one vector that fulfils such a thing.

If I find a vector $y\in W$ that fulfils the second condition, does it **definitely** fulfil the first condition?

If yes, does a vector that fulfil the first condition necessarily fulfil the second one?

---

Side note: since $y$ is supposed to be an unique vector, doesn't it have a name?

Comment: $y$ is called *the projection of x onto W*.

Comment: Or $y$ is the closest point (Kaballo also mentions best approximation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the first condition is implied by the second one, to see that, let $u \in W$. Then for any $t \in \mathbb R$: $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\def\<#1>{\left(#1\right)}$
$$
  \norm{x-y-tu}^2 = \norm{x-y}^2 + 2t\<x-y,u> + t^2\norm{u}^2 =: f(t) 
$$
Note that $f$ has a local minimum in $t=0$ by the second condition, giving 
$$ 0= f'(0) = 2\<x-y,u> $$
Hence $x-y \mathrel\bot W$.

Now suppose the first condition holds, then we have for any $u \in W$: 
\begin{align*}
  \norm{x-u}^2 &= \norm{x-y+y-u}^2\\
        &= \norm{x-y}^2 + 2\underbrace{\<x-y,y-u>}_{{}=0} + \norm{y-u}^2\\
        &\ge \norm{x-y}^2
\end{align*}
So both conditions are equivalent.

---

Yes, $y$ has a name, it is called the image of the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $W$, the map $P_W \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, $P_W x = y$ is called the orthogonal projection onto $W$.